# Excluding multiple attributes from being labeled in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling

I am using ArcMap 10.1, and i am labeling a roadway system but would like to exclude multiple road labels from being displayed. I know how to exclude one road at a time using SQL Query by typing road<>4, but I can't figure out how to type that in order to exclude more than one road.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out IN operator of SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there some way to type something similar to 'road<>4,8' and use that to exclude both roads 4 and 8? I have not been able to figure out the right combo of symbols and text to make this possible. @faith_dur

Comment: Road not in (4,9)

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications and additional information.